Disagree as to reason why my question was closed
My question was closed. The reason given is that the answer is "common knowledge".
I certainly do not believe it is common knowledge as to which mechanism is the best predictor of Bank of Canada policy rates.
I also do not believe it is "common knowledge" as to how to calculate probabilities from OIS as to the magnitude and direction of the next BoC rate decision.
If it is so common, please tell me where to find this information. If whoever closed the question can't do that, they should reopen the question.

I agree this is a valid question. I will re open.
Although it has duplicates those anwsers are not particularly good.
How to quantify how many ECB hikes are priced in?
Number of Fed Rate hikes prices in

Disagree with this decision. This question not only needed more focus but also the answers to some of them would be common knowledge among finance industry professionals or academics and/or would be opinion-based.

Pricing implied hikes/cut from interest rate instruments is quite a technical area that is poorly understood and has non-obvious peculiarities. I do not at all consider it to be basic common knowledge even among fellow traders. With regards to moderation if we scrutinise questions too closely we risk becoming a site that closes and shuts off too many questions. I prefer leaning towards openness and inclusion where it can provide helpful tuition for browsers. Particularly when something is subjective.

ixodid may well go on to become a strong contributor to the community. If he is put off early by having a question closed and then refuses to revisit the site, it may only be to the communities detriment, for the sake of simply reopening a single question.

@Attack68 I sense frustration with the high percentage of not very interesting questions. What can we do to increase the number of interesting ones?

@DimitriVulis My feedback is only about the reopening of the question mentioned in the original post and I still think the same.

I also voted to close this question, and I stand by my vote.

The OP has gone beyond the usual poster whose question is closed, by raising an appeal via Meta. Questions which are closed without appeal typically remain closed. The OP here has laid out a valid reason for his appeal. In support of his reasoning I would add that there are various complex, non-basic issues surrounding his question such as: what are the effects of compounding to RFR rates that impact the probabilities of rate hike decisions? What are the variabilities of the RFR - central bank policy basis that affect the probabilities priced in? What if an RFR market doesn't exist?

Thank you, @Attack68. Additionally, this question duplicates: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18890 https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31563 https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40484 https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49973 https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68970
